# How to restart an exe when it is exits in windows 10?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

I have a process in windows which i am running in startup. Now i need to make it if somehow that process get killed or stopped i need to restart it again in Windows 10?

Is there any way. Process is a HTTP server which if somehow stopped in windows i need to restart it. I have tried of writing a power-shell in which I'll check task-list status of process and then if not found I'll restart but that is not a good way. Please suggest some good way to do it.

I have a golang exe; under a particular scenario my process got killed or stopped i need to start it up again automatically. This has to be done imediately after the exe got killed. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you a brief rundown. You can enable `Audit Process Termination` in local group policy of the machine as shown below. In your case, `success` audits would be enough. Please note that the pic is for Windows 7. It may change with OS.

[image]

Now every time a process gets terminated, a success event will be generated and written to the security eventlog.

[image]

This will allow you to create a task scheduler that triggers on the generation of this event that calls a script that would run the process again. Simple right?

Well, you might have some trouble setting that task up especially when you want to pass details about the generating event to the script. [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/otto/2007/11/09/reference-the-event-that-triggered-your-task/) should help you get through that.

[image]

Comment: What is that you are trying to show as an answer? OPs question is related to restarting the process if its stopped or killed. Why should that be tracked like this? Run any background script which will constantly monitor the process status and if negative, it will start it back.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - What if the background script stops? This is a pretty lightweight, out of the box way to restart the process. I'm just not sure about the time it takes before everything kicks in to start again but resource wise, this is hard to beat.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: I still doubt from my experience that event based triggers in task scheduler results is huge resource consumption and affects production badly if the number of hits are pretty high. Another negative side is, it constantly sits in heap memory. There is nothing like garbage collector here.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - I don't have experience with event based triggers. You might be right about it having a noticable impact on a server with lots of processed created/destroyed but running another script to monitor a process, while easy to do, should raise some eyebrows too. Perhaps OP should look into moving the process into a service. That would have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Second you on this thought if it could be a service, then less overhead from OS stand point of view . :) Although, I was going through it and tried, it seems an unkempt version of what we are trying to achieve, but I thoroughly enjoyed it. [grin]

Comment: @RanadipDutta  I would love to do it with a service too. But writing one isn't easy. Even when you write it, it is always running on the background and querying this process what every 5 seconds and doing exactly what the task scheduler is doing? And that brings us to the rather annoying issue with home-made services: efficiency. They are more likely to have memory leakage and resource hogging issues than the inbuilt task scheduler. At the end of the day, we will have a process running anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can user Task scheduler for this purpose. There is a option of "restart on failure" which can be selected and whenever your process get failed it will restart again.

**Reference** :- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4545361c-cc1f-4505-a0a1-c2dcc094109a/restarting-scheduled-task-that-has-failed?forum=winserverManagement

Comment: That only applies to exe started using a scheduled task doesnt it?

Comment: correct @Sid. So he can start the exe using scheduler .